# How to convert string field array back into an array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im receiving from an API something like this

```js
"['item1', 'item2', 'item3']"
```

so even though it looks like an array is actually a string. I want to convert that to an array again so I did this.

```js
 let pseudoArray = "['item1', 'item2', 'item3']";
 let actualArray = pseudoArray.slice(1, -1).split(', ');
```

And it kinda works I just remove the brackets at the beginning and the end with `slice()` and use `split` to separate by the comma into an actual array.

But I feel this is not the best way to do it, is there a better, cleaner way to parse this string into an array?

Comment: Is `item1` supposed to be in quotes like item2 and item3?

Comment: yes I will fix it right away

Comment: Try and get the API endpoint to output valid JSON instead?

Comment: What if the items themselves have quotes in them?

Comment: `'['item1', 'item2', 'item3']'` isn't valid JS syntax. Are you sure it's not escaped quotes or double quotes? Can you `JSON.parse` it?

Comment: I think what you need to fix is API not anything in the front-end.

Comment: No one likes to recommend `eval` because of security concerns, but you could use it here `let str = "['item1', 'item2', 'item3']"; 
    let arr = eval(str);`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: You could always replace all the single quotes/apostrophes with double quotes and then `JSON.parse` it but I guess there's probably no guarantee that the text won't contain them!

Answer (score 1):

You could try matching the string patterns directly, like this:

```js
var items = "['item1', 'item2', 'item3']";
const array = items.match(/(?<=')[^,].*?(?=')/g);
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the better approach would be replace all single quote with double quotes.

```
var items = "['item1', 'item2', 'item3']";
items = items.replace(/'/g, '"') //replacing all ' with "
console.log(JSON.parse(items))
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: There is no parent quote. That is javascript syntax for strings, and you could start the string with a double quote and escape the inner ones.

Answer (score 0):

Just invert the characters `'` and `"` to get the correct JSON string:

```js
const str = "['item1', 'item2', 'item3']";

const mapping = {"'": '"', '"': "'"};
const jsonStr = str.replaceAll(/[\'\"]/g, (e) => mapping[e]);
const arr = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to first convert this normal string into a JSON string by replacing single quotes (`'`) with double quotes (`"`) and then convert that JSON string into JSON object by using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
let str = "['item1', 'item2', 'item3']";
str = str.replace(/'/g, '"');
console.log(JSON.parse(str));
```